# Asp.Net Core - Using Session variables in task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm building a simulator with Asp.Net application where simulation is done as a separate task. I'm having problem with accessing data which is processed in this task.

I've tried to access task or threat I created, but don't see a way to track created task.

I've also tried to use Session, but after request is completed I have no access to Session anymore, so background task stops with error.

**LatheController:**

```
public class LatheController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApiDbContext _dbContext;
    private static ILatheService _latheService;

    public LatheController(ApiDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public LatheCell GetLatheCell()
    {
        if (_latheService == null)
        {
           _latheService = new LatheService();

            _latheService.Start(lc);
        }

        return _latheService.GetLatheCell();
    }


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public LatheCell GetLatheCell([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        return AppHttpContext.Current.Session.GetObjectFromJson<LatheCell>("latheCell");
    }
}
```

**LatheService:**

```
public class LatheService : ILatheService
{
    private LatheSimulator _latheSim;

    public void Start(LatheCell lc)
    {
        _latheSim = new LatheSimulator(lc);

        Task task = new Task( () => { _latheSim.Start(); });
        task.Start();
    }

    public LatheCell GetLatheCell()
    {
        return _latheSim.GetLatheCell();
    }
}
```

**LatheSimulator:**

```
    public class LatheSimulator
{
    private LatheCell _latheCell;
    private bool _keepRunning;

    public LatheSimulator(LatheCell latheCell)
    {
        _latheCell = latheCell;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _keepRunning = true;
        Simulation();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _keepRunning = false;
    }

    public LatheCell GetLatheCell()
    {
        return _latheCell;
    }


    private void Simulation()
    {
        while (_keepRunning)
        {
            _latheCell.RunningCycle++;
            //// The simuation ///

            AppHttpContext.Current.Session.SetObjectAsJson("latheCell", _latheCell);

            //Sleep operation to simulate speed of the conveyor
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_latheCell.ConveyorIn.Speed);
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /// ... some other configurations

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    { 
       ///....
       app.UseSession();
       AppHttpContext.Services = app.ApplicationServices;
      /// .....
    }
```

**AppHttpContext:**

```
public static class AppHttpContext
{
    static IServiceProvider services = null;

    public static IServiceProvider Services
    {
        get { return services; }
        set
        {
            if (services != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can't set once a value has already been set.");
            }
            services = value;
        }
    }

    public static HttpContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = services.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;
            return httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could use database for this, but because I will be calling database every 5 sec in the simulation, I would like to keep simulator in the memory for the performance.

If anyone could put me in the right direction I will be very appreciated. I'm scratching my head for several days now.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to keep simulator in the memory for the performance.

The problem is if App Pool recycles and App Domain restarts, you will loose everything that task is running.

Ideally, we need to storage data in persistent storage like SQL Server. I'll say calling database every 5 sec is not a big deal, unless you are querying a lot of data to process.

We normally use background task such as [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). You could read more about other background tasks at Scott Hanselman's [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: I don't worry about AppPool as the simulation will not take longer than 30 minutes.

Comment: I have researched hangfire last week but that use Sql to store tasks

Comment: Well, if application hard crashes for whatever reason, app domain will restart. If any application hosted inside the app pool malfunction, it'll finally effect the app pool. Those are out of our control.

Comment: so are you suggesting that storing to database is the only reliable solution?

Comment: Yes, if you want reliable background task, then those data need to be stored at persistent storage.

Comment: I hate when I found out that what I've been avoiding for over week is the only right answer :-(

Comment: Do you have experience with hangfire? It doesn't allow to do continues tasks in seconds, how would you resolve this?

Comment: Pluralsight has a course called [Simplified .NET Background Tasks with Hangfire](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/simplified-dotnet-background-tasks-hangfire/table-of-contents). You could subscribe for a free trial. If you have more questions about hangfire, could you please create a new question?

Comment: But do this tutorial have solution for running in seconds iterations? Manual says minutes is the lowest right now? I can create new question but I'm not sure hangfire is the answer to my question. The question is how do I access varaibles created in the task?

Comment: I have never run background task in seconds; hangfire doens't seem to support in seconds. You might want to look at [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), but I have never used it